# Fabric js set background group image and text

Tags: html, canvas, background-image, fabricjs

Is it possible to add text and image both in canvas background?? like this

The image and the word 'Drag photo here'

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes!**

It is possible and here is how you can achieve that ...

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var text = new fabric.Text('DRAG PHOTO HERE', {
   top: 100,
   left: 100,
   fontSize: 14,
   fontFamily: 'Arial',
   originX: 'center',
   originY: 'center'
});

fabric.Image.fromURL('https://i.imgur.com/LKaEHRo.jpg', function(img) {
   img.setWidth(200);
   img.setHeight(200);
   var group = new fabric.Group([img, text]);
   canvas.setBackgroundImage(group);
   canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.13/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: That's exactly how to do it